# Как в php отправить запрос к базе не дожидаясь ответа?

Tags: php, база-данных

Знаю, что php однопоточный, но может быть есть какие-то методы чтобы просто отправить update или insert и продолжить ввполнение текущего скрипта не дожидаясь ответа базы? Желательно без системного вызова отдельного скрипта или ручной реализации этого через сокеты

Comment: Вы смотрели вообще скорость выполнения запросов update или insert? Копейки

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе не указано, но я предположил, что у Вас используется MySQL.

Для вставки новых записей есть `INSERT DELAYED ...`, которую MySQL примет в свою очередь и вернет ответ сразу до ее обработки. Но `INSERT DELAYED`, к сожалению, работает только для `MyISAM`, `MEMORY`, `ARCHIVE` и `BLACKHOLE` таблиц и возможно поэтому вам это не подойдет. Для команд обновления/удаления опции `DELAYED` - нет (((

Мне в голову пришли два возможных пути решения задачи, может это поможет Вам:

- попробывать использовать [диспетчер событий](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html), создавая разовые события, на выполнение по конкретному времени, с update / insert.

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

- попробывать использовать репликацию БД с двумя инстансами: "нагруженная запросами" - "ненагруженная". Вы отправляете запросы в ненагруженный инстанс, а синхронизация БД происходит прозрачно для Вас.